# my animation looks blur

Tags: animation, blur

https://youtu.be/WD4BXb5o1sI

In this video when i start that animation all the images, texts and other particles becomes pixelated and blurry. But when i stop that animation all the images, text and other particles become clear. So what can i do to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Now, check i inserted the link of the video.

Comment: I think the folks here will need far more details such as your Blender setup, images of your settings, etc. before being able to suggest anything. (And try spelling "Golden Compass" correctly! :^))

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @JohnEason Can you please be more specific about the settings. I'm using the preset settings of blender. I will be very grateful if you solve my problem. I m struggling with this problem for so many days so please help me.. and if you want any screenshot of the render settings I can give you that also....

Comment: since you seem to be a beginner - maybe for you the easiest way would be to provide your blend file

Comment: @chris how can i provide you the blend file. Can you please tell.

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @shubham I agree with chris. As long as the blend file is under 30 Meg in size you can use blend-exchange.com following the instructions on that page. You'll have to pack any images into your file first though via File > External Data > Pack Resources in Blender so it may be an idea to share a simplified file to keep the size down.

Comment: @Chris I uploaded the file can you please have a look at that file....

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=4yL8Mkxv" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/4yL8Mkxv/)

Comment: Hi Shubham, since you are moving the camera pretty fast, i would suggest to increase fps from 30 to 60.

Comment: here result for 60 fps: https://youtu.be/BbgLSg_Vl9Y and here for your 30 fps: https://youtu.be/TUOvASKqebY

Comment: @Chris Animation is still blur after changing the fps....

Comment: but do you see the difference at all or not? if yes, increase it even more...

Comment: @Chris there is hardly any difference ...

Comment: i see a big difference....

Comment: @Chris you are only looking at the first 100 frames in which everything is fine then after 100 frames it starts blurring again

Comment: @Chris is there are any other settings that you can suggest other than fps......

Comment: first of all, you should have set that you meant the frames after 100...i cannot read your mind. I just rendered the first few frames, made 2 videos for you and i saw a HUGE difference between these two, which you just denied instead of telling me that you rendered AFTER 100 frames. And my second problem is...i don't know why, but i cannot download your blend file anymore...